# Apply converters to all the columns while reading excel file, Python 3.6

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am importing excel file with 30 columns to dataframe and want to change column type of all the columns to string, how to do this?

```
data = pd.read_excel(excelPath, sheetname='Donor', converters={'Code':str})
```

Comment: `data = pd.read_excel(excelPath, sheetname='Donor', converters={k: str for k in range(30)})`.

Comment: @ thanks Abdou, its working...

Comment: A note about @Abdou's comment: if you don't know precisely how many columns are present, you're going to hit `IndexError: list index out of range` if you specify too large of a range, or you'll fail to convert all columns if you undershoot.

Answer (score 4):

For Pandas 0.20.0+ you can use `dtype=object` parameter:

```
data = pd.read_excel(excelPath, sheet_name='Donor', dtype='object')
```

from [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html):

> **dtype** : Type name or dict of column -> type, default None
>
> Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32}
>
> **Use object to preserve data as stored in Excel and not
> interpret dtype. If converters are specified, they will be applied
> INSTEAD of dtype conversion.**
>
> New in version 0.20.0.

Comment: `sheetname` should be now changed to `sheet_name`.

Comment: I found that `dtype='object'` still allowed for non-strings to come through in many cases.  Using `dtype=str` combined with `keep_default_na=False` made this solution viable, even when reading multiple different sheets simultaneously (using `sheet_name=None`).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to solution from @Plinus, the following code read all the headers (assuming it is at row 0). It reads **0** row of data.

Using the headers (column names), it creates a dictionary of "column name"-"data conversion function" pairs `converters`.

It then re-read the whole Excel file using the converters.

```
columns = pd.read_excel(
    '/pathname/to/excel/file.xlsx',
    sheet_name='Sheet 1',
    nrows=0, # Read 0 rows, assuming headers are at row 0
).columns

converters = {col: str for col in columns} # Convert all fields to strings
data = pd.read_excel(
    '/pathname/to/excel/file.xlsx',
    sheet_name='Sheet 1',
    convertes=converters        
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
converterS = {col: str for col in column_list} # Convert all field to string
data = pd.read_excel(excelPath, sheetname='Donor', converters=converterS )
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'column_list' is not defined`